# How to get ArcPy parameter of type Folder shown in Textbox?

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, parameters, python-toolbox

Writing an ArcPy toolbox for ArcGIS Pro I am having the issue that the declaration of the following code does give me a browse button and the associated textbox. However, using the browse button, and selecting a folder, does not lead to the selected folder shown in the associated textbox.

```
lyr04 = arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName="LYR directory",
                name="lyrx_dir",
                datatype="DEFolder",
                parameterType="Optional",
                direction="Input"
                )
```

Am I missing a cast, declaration or property definition?

I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.5.1 and Python 3.6

Here the code of a `*.pyt`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import arcpy


class Toolbox(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the toolbox (the name of the toolbox is the name of the
        .pyt file)."""
        self.label = "Toolbox"
        self.alias = ""

        # List of tool classes associated with this toolbox
        self.tools = [Tool]


class Tool(object):
    def __init__(self):
        """Define the tool (tool name is the name of the class)."""
        self.label = ""
        self.description = ""
        self.canRunInBackground = False

    def getParameterInfo(self):
        """Define parameter definitions"""
        
        lyr04 = arcpy.Parameter(
                displayName="LYR directory",
                name="lyrx_dir",
                datatype="DEFolder",
                parameterType="Optional",
                direction="Input"
                )

        params = [lyr04]
        return params

    def execute(self, parameters, messages):
    """The source code of the tool."""
        return
```

Comment: This looks like it *may* come from a Python Toolbox tool but is there any chance that you're trying to use it in a Python Script tool instead?  For a Python Toolbox tool I think its best to includes the whole `*.pyt` code of a test tool rather than a copy/paste.

Comment: PolyGeo, I don't get what you are asking. Of course this is just a snippet of the parameter definition (getParameterInfo) from the tool class within a *.pyt.

Comment: Your edit addresses what I was asking.  Now it's clearly a `*.pyt` that you're using.  You'd be amazed what gets copy/pasted from irrelevant code samples sometimes so I had to ask.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does not lead to the selected folder shown in the associated textbox" -- are you saying the folder you select in the tool isn't the folder that is passed into your code? Or can you explain that statement further?

Comment: When I select a directory through the browse button, then the select dialog closes, but the associated textbox stays empty. The user has no indication if a directory was selected or not. There is no point for me to check if there is a value for the directory or not if the user can't see it.